# generic filtering of JSON objects in js using Ramda

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming, filtering, ramda.js

I like the implementation to be as generic and functional (as in functional programming) as possible, but generally speaking, i'm expecting a json objected with the following structure:

```
[
 {
   id: number,
   prop1: string,
   prop2: number,
   prop3: string,
   ...,
   propN: string
 },
 ...
]
```

(basically, an array of object that contain N properties, some mapped to strings and others to numbers)

I am trying to implement a generic set of functions so that i'll be able to achieve something to this end:

```
var filteredResult = filter(by(property, value, lt\gt\eq\contains), collection);
```

basically, I'd like to return an array with the same object structure, filtered by a property string that I pass into by(), along with the value (either a string or a number) and the type of comparison i'd like to perform.

generally speaking, for numbers I'd like to be able to filter results where property values are greater/lessthan/in range of the value I pass, with with strings, or arrays of strings, I'd like to find out if the property value contains the value I pass into by().

Since I'm new to FP, i'm struggling with formatting my code to take advantage of the auto-currying Ramda provides and I'm having trouble composing the different functions while passing the arguments I want.

For example, I've written this function:

```
var byProperty = function(p) {return R.useWith(R.filter, R.propEq(p), R.identity)};
```

but when I try to use it like so:

```
var property = 'prop1', value = 15;
console.log( byProperty( property, value, collection ) );
```

I get a function instead of the filtered array.

I know I'm missing something trivial here, but it's been kind of hard for me to wrap my head around the way values and functions are passed around in Ramda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I try to use it like `console.log( byProperty( property, value, collection ) )` I get a function instead of the filtered array.

Yes, because your function takes only a single parameter, and returns a function. You could invoke it like this:

```
console.log( byProperty(property)(value, collection) );
```

but that's probably not what you want. Also, I think `useWith` is the wrong tool here, you just want a [`compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose):

```
var byProperty = R.compose(R.filter, R.propEq);
```

though that still would need to be called like

```
console.log( byProperty(property, value)(collection) );
```

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/736) for this, but currying and composing variadic functions is not trivial. The best you'll get is probably

```
var byProperty = R.curryN(3, function(p, v, c) { return R.filter(R.propEq(p, v), c); });
```

Comment: Thank you! This clears up a bunch of stuff for me. In your last example, would it be possible to pass a function reference as an argument, instead of the hard-coded R.propEq?

Comment: @airbag: Yes, you could. Just make sure `filter` gets called with what it expects - a predicate.